# Lightsaber canon reference

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I'm doing my senior essay on lightsaber science and history (as I am making a lightsaber hilt out of machined aluminum for my project).

I am looking for other references that I can put in my work cited page besides [wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) that give information about how lightsabers were crafted, and their lore and evolution (protosabers to modern lightsabers).

Is there a comprehensive list of current canon information on the crafting and history of lightsabers, including references (preferably also with quotations)?

Comment: I've made some edits to your question, as I fear in the original format it might garner some close votes due to seeming like an open-ended list. If you disagree with my edits, please feel free to revert them, or edit further.

Comment: Doesn't help with this question. But have you considered the sources linked to as references on wookiepedia? They are typically the books these things are discussed in.

Comment: This may be an interesting footnote for your essay, did you know they've actually [invented one](http://newsfeed.time.com/2013/10/01/someone-finally-invented-real-working-lightsabers/)?

Comment: yes i have taken the sources from wookiepedia and yes sindi i did add that to my report :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Scholastic book called "Lightsabers:  A Guide to Weapons of the Force."  It is geared towards youth, but has some interesting information on all of the major characters' lightsabers, including hilt lengths, hilt widths, material use in hilt, and the focusing crystals.

In the book "Jedi vs. Sith:  The Essential Guide to the Force" there is a chapter on lightsabers (pages 94 - 119).  The text is mostly historical rather than technical.  Some of the section headings are:

- Lightsaber Construction
- Improvised Lightsabers
- Archaic Lightsabers
- Waterproof Lightsabers
- Training Lightsabers
- Dual-Phase Lightsabers

Although I haven't read it, I'm sure "The New Essential Guide to Weapons and Technology" has plenty of information on lightsabers.

Comment: thank you so much with that added to my referances i turned my essay in. Lets hope for that A range! :D